# HTML CSS - Float Grid Center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to transfer over to float in CSS to create a 4x3 grid of images, and so far I have it. But I have tried `float: left/right;` and using `margin-left/right: auto;`. But the float will over-ride the margins and stay on the left or right.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("images/ThanksGivingBG.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  color: Orange;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px OrangeRed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: none;
}

th {
  padding: 5px float: initial;
}

img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving1.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving2.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving3.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving4.jpg"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving5.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving6.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving7.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving8.jpeg"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving9.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving10.jpg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving11.jpeg"></th>
      <th><img id="image1" src="images/ThanksGiving12.jpg"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for this layout, take a look to grid layout or flexbox

Comment: Yes, this is a misuse of tables. They should generally only be used for data presentation. Also, floats are an outdated layout strategy. I suggest avoiding them as well.

Comment: My assignment requires for me to use float, but..

Comment: Is this for school or for work to be deployed to the public?  If the latter, then you really should avoid using tables here, as it represents an accessibility antipattern to use tables for layout purposes.  However, if it is just a school exercise to be performed in the abstract and reviewed by your teacher, then it is fine.

Comment: Got it fixed, thank y' all! Just removed the table attributes, and changed the id's for each row, and did float: initial;